# Is there a way to pass SQL Table data into a C#.NET Console Application as a command line argument?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am dealing with a basic SQL table that holds simple information about emails. The email subject, body, and who it is being sent to. I also have a console application that accepts those same three pieces of data as command line arguments to run the program. Normally, the user manually defines the command line arguments. However - I was wondering if there is any way to automatically pass the SQL table data into my .NET program as command line arguments when my program starts up. That way I can automate that part of the process. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could but generally this is more than just a SQL table name.  What SQL instance and database does it reside under?  What are the user credentials?  If this is something you want to be soft-coded but it really won't change very much (but theoretically could change one day), you would use the App.Config file to define a ConnectionString to the SQL table.  Suggest you look at Help regarding ConnectionString and App.Config.

Comment: Provide your programm with a db connection info and implement the query in your code.

Comment: If the user email subject, body and receiver data is fixed then create a CSV file by exporting data from SQL through a scheduled export, then pass the CSV file name into your console app as a parameter. In your program you can load, iterate through the CSV file and process the data in the email list. Alternatively, like the previous suggestion from Davin is to configure your SQL connection in a config file and query and process that within your console app, which is a more self-contained solution.